# Hyphenation within a p-type column

Tags: tables, hyphenation

I've got the following table, which I'd prefer not to split, and it's slightly too wide for the page. How can I make some of the column headings hyphenate? I don't want to have to define a fixed width of each column or something like that; it'd be much simpler if I could make "Labiodental" be hyphenated as "Labio-dental", as that's the troublesome column.

```
\begin{table}[htpb]\small\capstart
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}fc|c c|c c|c c|c c|c c|c c|c c|c c|c c|}
            \hline
            \SetRowStyle{\bfseries} & \multicolumn{2}{-c|}{Bilabial} & \multicolumn{2}{-c|}{Labiodental} & \multicolumn{2}{-c|}{Dental} & \multicolumn{2}{-c|}{Alveolar} & \multicolumn{2}{-c|}{Retroflex} & \multicolumn{2}{-c|}{Palatal} & \multicolumn{2}{-c|}{Velar} & \multicolumn{2}{-c|}{Glottal} \tabularnewline\hline
            Nasal & & m & & & & \textsubbridge{n} & & & & & & ɲ & & & & \tabularnewline%\hline
            Plosive & p & & & & \textsubbridge{t} & & & & & & & & k & & & \tabularnewline%\hline
            Affricate & & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textsubbridge{t}θ} & ts & & ʈʂ & & tɕ & & & & & \tabularnewline%\hline
            Fricative & & & f & \multirow{2}{*}{ʋ} & θ & \multirow{2}{*}{ð} & s & & ʂ & & ɕ & & x & & h & \tabularnewline%\cline{1-4} \cline{6-6} \cline{8-17}
            Approximant & & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & & & & & & & j & & w & & \tabularnewline%\hline
            Lateral & & & & & & & & l & & & & & & & & \tabularnewline%\hline
            Rhotic & & & & & & & & r\textasciitilde\textfishhookr & & & & & & & & \tabularnewline\hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Consonants\label{tab:consonants}}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please complete your code to a minimally working example as I can't get it to compile because I don't know what packages I am missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Use a multiline cell, such as a `p` column
- TeX doesn't hyphenate the first word of a paragraph, you can insert `\hspace{0pt}` to work around it.

This example will be hyphenated as desired:

```
\multicolumn{2}{p{1cm}|}{\hspace{0pt}Labiodental}
```

[image: hyphenation in cell]

This workaround can be efficiently used with the `>{...}` feature of the array package or even `\newcolumntype`, if it's required more often. Simply applied to this example in `\multicolumn`:

```
\multicolumn{2}{>{\hspace{0pt}}p{1cm}|}
```

Comment: Thanks. It just fits; I think I might have to decrease the margins a bit as well, as I have quite a lot of tables that are that mm or so too wide.