# How to set the width of my table?

Tags: tables, width, diagbox

I've some trouble to set the right width for my table. As you can see in the code below, I use the `diagbox` package to format my tables header.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{| l | c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \diagbox[width=7.5em, trim=l]{Symptom}{Auswirkung\\auf} & körp. Gesundheit & soziales Umfeld  & psych. Wohlbefinden & Selbstbestimmung \\
    \hline
    Körperpflege        & sehr hoch &  hoch  & hoch & gering  \\
    \hline
    Schlafrhythmus   & sehr hoch & gering & hoch & gering \\
    \hline
    Apathie                & hoch & sehr hoch & hoch &  \\
    \hline
    Agitation              & hoch & hoch & hoch &   \\
    \hline
    Essstörungen       & sehr hoch & gering & hoch & hoch \\
    \hline
    Haushaltsartikel& hoch & gering & gering & hoch \\
    \hline
\end{tabular*}%
\caption{caption goes here}
\label{tab:label goes here}
\end{table}
```

By using this code I'm getting the following result:

[image: By using this code I'm getting the following result]
Whoever the last column does not fit with the page width. I already tried to use manual line breaks but that didn't worked out. Do you have any tips or solutions for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `tabularx` and, of course, use less tabular lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,diagbox,ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| l | *4{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X|}} \hline
    \diagbox[width=7.5em, trim=l]{Symptom}{Auswirkung\\auf} & körp. Gesundheit & soziales 
    Umfeld  & psych. Wohlbefinden & Selbstbestimmung \\
    \hline
    Körperpflege        & sehr hoch &  hoch  & hoch & gering  \\
    \hline
    Schlafrhythmus   & sehr hoch & gering & hoch & gering \\
    \hline
    Apathie                & hoch & sehr hoch & hoch &  \\
    \hline
    Agitation              & hoch & hoch & hoch &   \\
    \hline
    Essstörungen       & sehr hoch & gering & hoch & hoch \\
    \hline
    Haushaltsartikel& hoch & gering & gering & hoch \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
My version:

\bigskip\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l | *4{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}}   
    \diagbox[width=7.5em, trim=l]{Symptom}{Auswirkung\\auf} & körp. Gesundheit & soziales 
    Umfeld  & psych. Wohlbefinden & Selbstbestimmung \\
    \hline
    Körperpflege        & sehr hoch &  hoch  & hoch & gering  \\
    Schlafrhythmus   & sehr hoch & gering & hoch & gering \\
    Apathie                & hoch & sehr hoch & hoch &  \\
    Agitation              & hoch & hoch & hoch &   \\
    Essstörungen       & sehr hoch & gering & hoch & hoch \\
    Haushaltsartikel& hoch & gering & gering & hoch \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagbox,tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| l | *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
\diagbox[width=7.5em, trim=l]{Symptom}{Auswirkung\\auf} 
    &   körp.  Gesundheit
        &   soziales  Umfeld 
            &   psych.  Wohlbefinden 
                &   Selbst\-bestimmung 
                                                                \\
    \hline
Körperpflege        & sehr hoch &  hoch     & hoch  & gering    \\
    \hline
Schlafrhythmus      & sehr hoch & gering    & hoch  & gering    \\
    \hline
Apathie             & hoch      & sehr hoch & hoch  &           \\
    \hline
Agitation           & hoch      & hoch      & hoch  &           \\
    \hline
Essstörungen        & sehr hoch & gering    & hoch  & hoch      \\
    \hline
Haushaltsartikel    & hoch      & gering    & gering & hoch     \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}%
\caption{caption goes here}
\label{tab:label goes here}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

you will get:

[image]

In stead `{tabular*}` I rather use `tabularx` and modified `X` column type. It centering cells content and what is more important: automatically determine columns width that they fit in prescribed `tabularx` width and *broke cells content* into *more lines*, if it is longer than column width. With this is eliminated your problem: the sum of the columns width is due to wide column heads larger than `\textwidth`.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to Zarko's, but the gist of either is that you have to enable hyphenation, otherwise the words are simply too long to fit on one line.

I also cleaned up the formatting with the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157400
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{lcccc}\toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Auswirkung auf} \\ 
    Symptom & \multicolumn{1}{P{1.8cm}}{körp. Gesundheit} &
    \multicolumn{1}{P{1.8cm}}{soziales Umfeld} &
    \multicolumn{1}{P{1.8cm}}{psych. Wohlbefinden} &
    \multicolumn{1}{P{1.8cm}}{\hspace{0pt}Selbstbestimmung} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18794/3345
    \\ \cmidrule{2-5} 
    Körperpflege        & sehr hoch &  hoch  & hoch & gering  \\
    Schlafrhythmus   & sehr hoch & gering & hoch & gering \\
    Apathie                & hoch & sehr hoch & hoch &  \\
    Agitation              & hoch & hoch & hoch &   \\
    Essstörungen       & sehr hoch & gering & hoch & hoch \\
    Haushaltsartikel& hoch & gering & gering & hoch \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}%
\caption{caption goes here}
\label{tab:label goes here}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```